# Rails - Translating values from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mongoid, translation

Sometimes I have to translate content from database like

```
    %td.language= t "mongoid.values.user.languages.#{@user.language}"
```

But it feels really ugly to me. Is there a rails method for that? Atm, the only solution i found is a monkey patch like

https://github.com/tobyhinloopen/onzinv8/blob/master/lib/human_attribute_value.rb

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Write a helper function that builds the string for you. That will clean up your views, if that is your concern.

Comment: I could, but then not as a helper. But that's not the point of my question. I can't beliefe that there is no such mothod in Active Model Translation, Active Record or whathever.